# Very basic cyclic groups question

Tags: group-theory

I'm just looking to prove that there is a isomorphism between the groups $C_2\times C_3$ and $C_6$ but I am struggling with the basics.

I know that $C_2$ consists of $e, x$ so I'm just wondering what the elements of $C_2 \times C_3$  are.

Thanks

Comment: $C_2$ consists of just $e$ and $x$.

Comment: The index $n$ in $C_n$ is the number of elements. So $C_2$ has only $2$ elements. For what you are looking to prove, has been proved here, e.g. in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271223/isomorphism-of-a-product-c-n-times-c-m-of-cyclic-groups-with-the-cyclic-group?rq=1).

Comment: Okay I have corrected that then, thank you. So what are the elements of $C_2 \times C_3$

Comment: Please see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241937/which-groups-are-isomorphic-c-2-times-c-3-c-6-and-s-3/2241958#)

Answer (score 0):

Let the generator of $C_2$ be $a$.

Let the generator of $C_3$ be $b$.

Then, $C_2 = \{e_a,a\}$ and $C_3 = \{e_b,b,b^2\}$.

Then, $C_2 \times C_3 = \{(e_a,e_b),(e_a,b),(e_a,b^2),(a,e_b),(a,b),(a,b^2)\}$.

It is generated by $(a,b)$:

$$(a,b) \mapsto (e_a,b^2) \mapsto (a,e_b) \mapsto (e_a,b) \mapsto (a,b^2) \mapsto (e_a,e_b)$$

Comment: okay thats perfect, thank you. I'm looking to prove the homomorphism between $C_2 \times C_3$  and $C_6$. I understand that there needs to be an element of order 6 in both. How do I know that there is an element of order 6 in $C_2 \times C_3$ ?

Comment: And $C_6 \cong C_{2\times 3}$ because $2, 3$ are coprime.

Comment: @juper I just showed you that element.

Comment: oh, are we saying that because the group $C_2 \times C_3$ is order 6 or there is an element in $C_2 \times C_3$  of order 6? sorry for the confusion on my part. i'm very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the iso it can be given by $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_3 \to \mathbb{Z}_6$, $(x,y)\to 3x+y$.