# Isomorphism of finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Prove:

a) $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \ncong \mathbb{Z}_4$

b) $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \cong \mathbb{Z}_{10}$

For a) I figured out that in $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ every element is its own inverse and in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ that is not the case and I'm not sure if that is enough to show they aren't isomorphic.

For b) I don't know how to find isomorphism.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For a), that is enough.  For b), map $(1,0)$ to $5$ and $(0,1)$ to $2$

Comment: For (a). Yes, of course it is enough to show that they are not isomorphic.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Having multiple questions in the same post is discouraged and such posts may be put on hold, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you, could you elaborate why you chose those mapings, could I map them to something different.

Comment: @Shaun I will keep that in mind, thanks

Comment: you need to map $(1,0)$ to something of order $2$ in $\mathbb Z_{10}$, which is $5$; you could map $(0,1)$ to anything of order $5$ in $\mathbb Z_{10}:  2, 4, 6, $ or $8$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a theorem stating that $C_m \times C_n$ is cyclic (and then isomorphic to $C_{mn}$) if and only if $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)=1$.

Comment: I'm familier with the theorem, do you have a proof of it?

Comment: See e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271223/isomorphism-of-a-product-c-n-times-c-m-of-cyclic-groups-with-the-cyclic-group